# fortran debugging problem

Tags: ide, fortran

I have compiled code but it doesn't work properly.My makefile:

```
FC= ifort
LD = ifort -align all
FCFLAGS = -O0 -g -ipo -traceback -warn noalign
LDFLAGS = $(FCFLAGS)

# Executables
nray: main.o findnode.o plots.o segmnt.o empty.o aldone.o erase.o pcolor.o box.o plot.o axtick.o axis.o line.o pltsrcbox.o find.o dot.o grad.o intersect.o straight.o backproj.o ddtime.o kernel.o resolution.o plotnd.o bndinterpret.o time.o $< $(INCS)
    $(FC) $(LDFLAGS)  $(FCFLAGS) -o nray main.o findnode.o plots.o segmnt.o empty.o aldone.o erase.o pcolor.o box.o plot.o axtick.o axis.o line.o pltsrcbox.o find.o dot.o grad.o intersect.o straight.o backproj.o ddtime.o kernel.o resolution.o plotnd.o bndinterpret.o time.o $< $(INCS)
main.o:main.f ray.par ray.com
    $(FC)  $(FCFLAGS) -c main.f
```

So if I want to see why backproj.o is not working,what should I do?

```
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 29, file /home/milenko/fast/ray/num.cell
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
nray               080CBD03  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
nray               080CAA20  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
nray               080950BE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
nray               0805E7AC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
nray               0805E0AA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
nray               0806B83D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
nray               0804C6BB  MAIN__                    226  main.f
num.cell is empty.
Breakpoint 1.1 at 0x804c5d5: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.2 at 0x804c887: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.3 at 0x804c8fa: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.4 at 0x804ca94: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.5 at 0x804cb0e: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.6 at 0x804cc2b: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.7 at 0x804cc97: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.8 at 0x804cfa4: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.9 at 0x804cff2: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.10 at 0x804e527: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.11 at 0x804e73d: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.12 at 0x804f07b: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.13 at 0x804f142: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.14 at 0x804f2e4: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.15 at 0x804f3ab: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.16 at 0x8053eda: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.17 at 0x8053ff2: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.18 at 0x8054168: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.19 at 0x80542c2: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.20 at 0x8054546: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.21 at 0x80545c8: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.22 at 0x8054cef: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.23 at 0x8054dc8: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.24 at 0x80551f4: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.25 at 0x8055261: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.26 at 0x80552bc: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.27 at 0x8055321: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.28 at 0x80553aa: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.29 at 0x805541e: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.30 at 0x8056bc6: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.31 at 0x8056cb3: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.32 at 0x8056d10: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.33 at 0x8056dd3: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.34 at 0x8056e54: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.35 at 0x8056f17: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.36 at 0x805784b: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.37 at 0x8057af0: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.38 at 0x8057b4d: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.39 at 0x8057df9: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.40 at 0x8057eb9: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.41 at 0x8057f45: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.42 at 0x8057fd8: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
Breakpoint 1.43 at 0x8058064: file /home/milenko/fast/ray/main.f, line 226.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading past the end of the file:

```
/home/milenko/fast/ray/num.cell
```

this is either because num.cell isn't long enough or your reading routine isn't stopping at the right place. The offending read is at line 226 of main.f or at least called there.

Can't really say much more without seeing some code.

It seems unlikely the problem is with backproj.f (doesn't sound like the sort of routine which should/will be reading a file) but that's just a guess based on the names of your routines.

Comment: Ok.I am giving the backproj.o

Answer (score 1):

You are getting and end of file error from the fortran runtime library trying to read the file `num.cell`. The first step should be to check whether the contents of that file are valid.